# kafka record contract validation before consuming it

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, validation, apache-kafka

I am currently working on the use case, where I'm consuming the records from kafka and doing the processing on those records. But the problem is, sometimes from the producer end we receive records with null fields or sometimes even the kafka record contract is breaking.

I want to log those records and take the decision where might be the problem at producer end.

So to achieve the task, I need to add validations before consuming it.
Record is nothing but array of bytes.

```
public Status process(Record record) {
    CartSessionNRT csNRT = Json.deserialize(record.getValue(), CartSessionNRT.class);
    consumeRecord(csNRT);
}

public class Record {
    private byte[] keyBytes;
    private byte[] valueBytes;
}


@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@ToString
public class CartSessionNRT {
    @JsonProperty("win_start")
    private String windowStart;
    @JsonProperty("win_end")
    private String windowEnd;
    @JsonProperty("time_stamp")
    private Long currentTimeStamp;
    @JsonProperty("restaurant_id")
    private Long restaurantId;
    @JsonProperty("cart_sessions")
    private Integer cartSessions;
}
```

What is the best ways to add the validations, I don't want to add validation in json property, because we won't be able to see the record values.

Please let me know Incase more details I need to add.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you can append `fixed length` byte array to value. without json decode, read that value and do the validation.

After json encode your value before produce, add fixed length byte array which contain your validations.
`[<validation part><json message>]`

Then your consumer side, before decode the json, read that appended byte array and do the validation. After that remove that byte slice from the main byte array and pass for other processes.

This is the way Avro encoded Kafka messages send that encoded schema ID with the Kafka message in confluent platform

reference - [wire-format](https://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format)

Comment: No. Actually, appending length is not possible as it is a library which is being used by multiple client, If we add something in code, then their code will see the impact.


I deserialized into a temporary object having same keys but type as Object of all the fields. And then checked the type of object. If something is unwanted then threw exception.

Comment: Problem is solved. I'm not sure If this is the correct way of solving the problem or not.